# Dynamically fill Artifact version from Artifactory in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, dynamic, version, artifactory

Is there a way I can using Dynamic parameter in Jenkins to populate a dropdown of artifact versions using their REST API? It needs to be in Groovy so I can make use of the Dynamic Choice Parameter Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The Artifactory [version search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactVersionSearch) REST API method can be used to get a list of all available artifact versions by GroupId and ArtifactId in local, remote or virtual repositories.
For example:

```
GET /api/search/versions?g=org.acme&a=artifact&repos=libs-release-local
{
"results": [
    {
    "version": "1.2",
    "integration": false
    },{
        "version": "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "integration": true
    },{
        "version": "1.0",
    "integration": false
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Can thier jenkins plugin do this?

Comment: @red888 Not sure which Jenkins plugin you mean, but if it has an ability to call a REST API than the answer is yes